# Translate Python requests code to Java (UniRest)

Tags: java, python, http, post, unirest

I am working with the Snapchat API to make a Java Client.  I am using an endpoint which takes the following parameters from an `HTTP POST`:

```
{
username: snapchat username,
timestamp: UNIX timestamp,
media_id: random string,
type: 0,
req_token: request token,
data: encrypted data
}
```

I have no problem generating the params hash, and I have the `data` as a `File` object.

In Python I have confirmed that the following works:

```
f = open('encrypted.jpg')
params = { ... all params besides data ... }
files = { 'data' : f }
r = requests.post(path, params, files=files)
```

That Python code gets me a 200.  I am using tokens and data/files generated by Java code, so the data sent is identical.

In Java I am doing the following with UniRest:

```
Map<String, Object> params = ... same params ...;
File f = new File('encrypted.jpg');
HttpRequestWithBody req = Unirest.post(path);
req.fields(params);
req.field("data", f);
HttpResponse<String> resp = req.asString();
```

However this gives me a 500 response from the server.  How can I write Java that emulates the Python exactly?  Or how can I snoop my own network traffic to see the difference in what the code for each is doing?  Seems crazy to me that one works and the other does not.

Comment: Should that read `req.field("data", f);`?

Comment: Yeah sorry, updated to correct that typo.

Comment: try to chain methods, i.e. req = Unirest.post(path).fields(params).field("data", f), or change the lines: req = req.fields(params); req = req.field("data", f);

Comment: @Marat wow, that's so simple it makes me angry.   I've spent days messing with this!  Chaining methods was the answer.  Not very Java-y I guess that's what I should expect from a multi-language REST library though.

Please re-state your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to chain methods, i.e.

```
req = Unirest.post(path).fields(params).field("data", f);
```

or change the lines:

```
req = req.fields(params); 
req = req.field("data", f);
```

Comment: The first part about chaining is the better way.  The `req = ...` way is more awkward because `Unirest.post(...)` returns an instance of `HttpRequestWithBody` but then calling `.field(...)` on that object returns an instance of a different class called `MultipartBody`.  So it's better to just chain it all together so you only work with the `MultipartBody` class.